# How can i view if user has edited a record or added a new record

Tags: 2013, list, list-view

I have a view with the "Last Modified" field showing, I want to know how many records are being added daily is there a way for this?  Also it seems that 100 records got "Modified" today, how can I check if this was a new record or existing record that was edited?

Comment: Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

In the View Settings:

- Add the Created and Modified dates to your view
- open the Group-By section and group by the your date field.
  sort Descending
- Open the (View) Totals section (below the Group By) and Total by **Count** for your date field

Answer (score 0):

Group the view by the 'last modified' date - it will group on the date only, not including the time. The 'header' for each group will show the counts - if you set it to start in collapsed mode it will be easier to see the totals.

As far as checking whether they are modified or new, you can check to see whether Modified is equal to Created. Can't do that in a view, so I'd do a calculated field with the calculation =IF([Created]=[Modified],"New","Modified")
and filter on that field.